# Open specific links in browser, instead of webview by regex

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm using parts of code form some tutorial to create webview app. Goals is - to open links, that not contain *appdev365* in browser, not in webview. I am completly noob at android development, so all that i've searched - didn't match to my(from tutorial) code.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.ynt;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.content.Intent;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://yatln.com/appdev365/index.php");

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ynt">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Y&amp;T База талантов"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ynt.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

SOLUTION (by Varma Lanke):
https://gist.github.com/codedamage/8f98e2ed13d1d1fa05e5d43e67ea3e6c

```
    private  WebView htmlWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        htmlWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        htmlWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSetting = htmlWebView.getSettings();
        webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSetting.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        htmlWebView.loadUrl("https://yatln.com/appdev365/index.php");
    }


    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.contains("appdev365"))
                view.loadUrl(url);
            else{
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
               // view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you should use shouldOverrideUrlLoading method, once try the below one

```
 private  WebView htmlWebView;
 String url = "https://yatln.com/appdev365/index.php";
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);


     htmlWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    if(url.contains("appdev365"))
    htmlWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

    WebSettings webSetting = htmlWebView.getSettings();
    webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSetting.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    htmlWebView.loadUrl(url);
}


private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.equalsIgnoreCase("appdev365"))
            view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, so where i should place it(file, after which line)? did i need to change any code in other files? Did i mentioned, that i using Android Studio at third time in my life? :)

Comment: Tried to place code instead of `private WebView webView;`  - IDE throws `no suitable method found for loadUrl(no arguments)`

Comment: @VikBlack, Please check the edited answer and one more thing please put u r min efforts. thank u

Comment: Ok, now i can't go to any page exept index, all links are non-active, external links ton working too. Sorry, but i'm doing my best, and i don't understand why this is so compicated, to open 2 links in browser not in app, working with this problem all day :(

Comment: @VikBlack, did u finish the task?

Comment: nope, trying to understand the problem, and why code not working as expected

Comment: @VikBlack, give me remote access, anydesk?

Comment: Maybe teamviewer?

Answer (score 0):

This code opens browser and specified link (ex. google.com):

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: Tired, IDE throws errors, like cannot find symbol variable Uri
or cannot find symbol variable mContext

Comment: import android.net.Uri